# how to make a clay-like physic simulation?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I'm trying to make a clay pressed by a rotating glass(like pic 1), I've tried soft body but it looks like a rubber ball(pic 2). Is there someway to simulate the clay-like texture?

what i want

[image]

my animation

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Soft Body** - *Mass* zero, *Edge > Pull* zero, *Bending* 1
To make sticky flat surface in contact with glass I duplicated collision object (glass) moved a bit lower (parent) and used for *Boolean modifier* (type *Exact*).

[image]

I also animated Sphere location to get better shape.

[image]

*Anyway (when I see result) you don't need to use simulation, for such thing you can just animate a sphere's scale and boolean modifier.*

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: may I ask another question?I've set the soft body like you told, but the sphere bobs all the time, is there something I  got wrong?

Comment: I don't know what "bob" means ... But these sims are very sensitive on topology .... If you use  more dense mesh (more vertices) result is totally different.

Comment: (sr for my English),the sphere vibrate like a jelly ,not a stable object:  [the GIF](https://gyazo.com/d79b996df9b6bdf8e00c376c52657f76)

Comment: oh its the sphere to close to the plane, it worked ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can set *Edges > Plasticity* to `100` so it will permanently deform. This way you don't have to end the simulation on a specific frame.