# How do I keep the shape resulted by the physics simulation

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I am trying to simulate clay and found this answer: [how to make a clay-like physic simulation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247524/how-to-make-a-clay-like-physic-simulation). The answer has a .blend file and I am trying to recreate it. In that .blend file a plane moves up-and-down, squashing a icosphere. When the plane moves up the icosphere keeps it's squashed shape. But when I recreate it in a different project, the clay returns to it's original shape. So how do I keep the shape resulted by the physics simulation.

(I didn't have enough points to comment)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to stop the simulation at the frame you want it to end.

Change this value in the cache part:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set *Edges > Plasticity* to `100` so it will permanently deform. This way you don't have to end the simulation on a specific frame.